# Clustering time series R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe of 20 x 20 ! Each row contains a time series. 
I have used regular kmeans method to group rows showing similar patterns however, it seems that other methods of clustering are used on time series.

Any ideas on how to cluster the time series below?

```
structure(list(X1 = c(0.92, 0.93, 0.65, 0.82, 1, 1), X2 = c(0.8286, 
0.8323, 0.4786, 0.722, 0.9899, 0.987), X3 = c(0.7794, 0.7794, 
0.3856, 0.6682, 0.9537, 0.9795), X4 = c(0.7462, 0.7439, 0.3308, 
0.6325, 0.9288, 0.9741), X5 = c(0.7215, 0.7175, 0.2937, 0.6061, 
0.9099, 0.97), X6 = c(0.7019, 0.6966, 0.2665, 0.5853, 0.8948, 
0.9666), X7 = c(0.6858, 0.6794, 0.2455, 0.5683, 0.8822, 0.9638
), X8 = c(0.6721, 0.6649, 0.2286, 0.554, 0.8714, 0.9614), X9 = c(0.6602, 
0.6523, 0.2147, 0.5417, 0.862, 0.9592), X10 = c(0.6498, 0.6413, 
0.203, 0.5309, 0.8537, 0.9573), X11 = c(0.6405, 0.6314, 0.1929, 
0.5213, 0.8462, 0.9556), X12 = c(0.6322, 0.6226, 0.1842, 0.5127, 
0.8395, 0.954), X13 = c(0.6246, 0.6146, 0.1765, 0.505, 0.8333, 
0.9525), X14 = c(0.6176, 0.6072, 0.1696, 0.4979, 0.8277, 0.9512
), X15 = c(0.6112, 0.6005, 0.1635, 0.4914, 0.8224, 0.95), X16 = c(0.6053, 
0.5942, 0.158, 0.4853, 0.8176, 0.9488), X17 = c(0.5998, 0.5884, 
0.153, 0.4797, 0.813, 0.9477), X18 = c(0.5946, 0.583, 0.1484, 
0.4745, 0.8088, 0.9467), X19 = c(0.5898, 0.5779, 0.1442, 0.4697, 
0.8047, 0.9457), X20 = c(0.5852, 0.5731, 0.1403, 0.4651, 0.801, 
0.9448)), row.names = c("D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It looks, from your data, that you only have 1 column in the data set. Is that right?

Comment: No, excluding the first column which contains the diseases, there are 20 other columns; survival rate at Yr1 to survival rate at Yr 20

Comment: It could be easier if you could give a data example/sample...  And it is also possible to insert a picture to the post (there is a button for that).

Comment: use `dput(head(test1))` to show us the data

Answer (score 2):

Please try the *dtwclust* package in R. This provides various distance based clustering algorithms.

An alternative is to follow to feature based clustering technique, which instead of capturing similarity of point values using a distance metric, use sets of global features obtained from a time series to summarise and describe the salient information of the time series. The feature-based clustering is comprised of two stages, namely a
feature extraction phase and the clustering phase, for which standard clustering approaches can be used. For the feature extraction phase, you can use *tsfeatures* package in R. Afterwards, for the extracted feature set, you can apply your favourite clustering algorithm (kMeans, DBCluster, etc.)

Thanks.

[1] https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dtwclust/versions/3.1.1/topics/dtwclust

[2] https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsfeatures/vignettes/tsfeatures.html